# How can I add a website link in a button using kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin

How to add a website link in a button using kotlin in android?

Comment: Do you want to add hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate what is your exact requirement with code that you have tried.....

If you want to `open link in browser when you click on a button` then do this,

```
button.setOnClickListener{
    try{
        val uri = Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/") 
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri) 
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    catch(e : ActivityNotFoundException){
    }
}
```